# Connected sets and intersection of sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $M\subset X$ such that $M$ is connected, then choose $N_1,...,N_q \subset X$, where $N_i$ are not necessarily connected,  then would $M\cap N_1\cap...\cap N_q$ be connected as well?

I think this will be a yes, consider below:

let $f:M\cap N_1\cap...\cap N_q\to\{0, 1\}$ be continuous. Assume $M\cap N_1\cap...\cap N_q$ is non-empty, then take $x,y\in M\cap N_1\cap...\cap N_q$. Then $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $x,y\in M\cap N_1\cap...\cap N_q$ due to the fact that $x,y\in M$ and $M$ is connected. So $f$ is a constant function and hence $M\cap N_1\cap...\cap N_q$ is connected?

If that is the case, then does it mean that one subset's connectedness will ensure the connectedness of finite amount of intersection of arbitrary subsets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to have $f(x) = f(y)$ when $x,y \in M$, since $f$ does not have domain $M$ nor it can be restricted to $M$ since its domain may be strictly contained in $M$.

Recall that $M$ is connected if and only if every continuous function $M \to \{0,1\}$ (that is, with **domain M** and codomain the $2$-point discrete space) is constant.

Taking $N := N_1 = \cdots = N_q$ and $M = X$, your claim says that $X$ connected implies $N \subset X$ connected and this is false: for example by considering $\{0,1\} \subset  \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: +1.... $M\cap N_1\cap ....\cap N_q$ can be any subset of $M.$